# Is it allowed to start multiple transactions in the same Sqlite database connection?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a multi-threaded C++ application which uses Sqlite3 for the database. I am storing the SQLite database connection and threads which need access to the database, use the same connection creating the transactions of their own.

I use the below command to get the database connection.

```
const int errorCode =  sqlite3_open_v2(fileNameUtf8.c_str(), &Handle, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, Vfs->GetName().c_str());
```

But as multiple threads are accessing the database, I am facing the issue of starting multiple transactions in the same connection. When the second thread tries to begin transaction error message "cannot start a transaction within a transaction" is returned.

I thought SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX flag allows the case of multiple threads using the same connection. I assumed it might even allow multiple transactions in the same connection.

Is there any option in Sqlite3 to begin multiple transactions corresponding to different threads using the same SQLite database connection ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, one connection corresponds to one transaction.
To get separate transactions, you need separate connections.

Accessing one connection from multiple threads makes sense only if the threads ensure that their transactions and SQL statements do not interfere with each other.

Also read the [FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple independant transation in same single connexion simply does not make sense: since you use the same connection, every other transaction is seen by the database as *nested* in the already existing one, so the error.

But if you need concurrency, you should wonder whether SQLite is the right tool. From the FAQ [Appropriate Uses For SQLite :](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

> SQLite does not compete with client/server databases. SQLite competes with fopen().

and later

> Many concurrent writers? → choose client/server